# Nav bar won't render correctly

Tags: html, css

My Navigation bar seems to extend out further than where the rest of my page stops. See my code within a JSfiddle with what's happening [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathanmpower/ub1m3ch6/). I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

HTML:

```
<div id="header-wrapper">
            <center>
                <a href="index.html" id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""/></a>
            </center>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="12u">
                        <header id="header">
                            <nav id="nav">
                                <a href="index.html" class="current current-page-item"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp Home</a>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-flag-o"></i>&nbsp RFP Recap '14-'15</a>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-database"></i>&nbsp Archived Updates</a>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp Contact Us</a>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i>&nbsp Member Contacts</a>
                                <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>&nbsp Log In</a>
                            </nav>
                      </header>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Header */

    #header-wrapper {
        background-color: #007294;
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #008dab, #007294);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #008dab, #007294);
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#008dab), to(#007294));
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #008dab, #007294);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #008dab, #007294);
        background-image: linear-gradient(top, #008dab, #007294);
    }

    #header {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #006e8b;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #12a0bf, 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    background-color: #007b9d;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #008ead, #007b9d);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #008ead, #007b9d);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#008ead), to(#007b9d));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #008ead, #007b9d);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #008ead, #007b9d);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #008ead, #007b9d);
    height: 86px;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2.5%;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0px;
    }

        #header h1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.4em;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    line-height: 86px;
        }

        #header h1 a {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #header nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
    top: 1px;
    line-height: 84px;
    text-transform: ;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    width: 1066px;
    height: 92px;
        }

            #header nav a {
                display: inline-block;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #fff;
                padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
                outline: 0;
            }

            #header nav a.current-page-item {
                background-color: #007897;
                background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #007b99, #007897);
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #007b99, #007897);
                background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#007b99), to(#007897));
                background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #007b99, #007897);
                background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #007b99, #007897);
                background-image: linear-gradient(top, #007b99, #007897);
                box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
            }

            #header nav a:hover {
                background-color: #0882a1;
                background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0782a0, #077d9b);
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0782a0, #077d9b);
                background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0782a0), to(#077d9b));
                background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0782a0, #077d9b);
                background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0782a0, #077d9b);
                background-image: linear-gradient(top, #0782a0, #077d9b);
                box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
            }
```

Comment: Can you share your jsfiddle?

Comment: @JustinBreiland Apologies. I accidentally posted the question without correctly hyperlinking the JSfiddle and adding the html and css. Please see the revised post.

Comment: your css has `#header { width: 1200px; }` which is bigger than your parent div, if you get rid of that it'll fit properly but then the children of header need to be readjusted `#header nav {  width: 1066px;} ` remove this too

Comment: @racecarjonathan, thanks for updating. change #header { width:auto;}

Comment: @JustinBreiland I have updated #header with { width:auto; } but the tabs are all moved towards the left. The "Home" tab is completely off the nav bar now. Thoughts?

Comment: @racecarjonathan, whoops I forgot that the nav is set to abolute.  It also has right: 40px so it is pushing everything to the left.  You sould be able to set the nav to position: relative.  Would you like it to scale with the width?

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/6r0wo91h/

Comment: @JustinBreiland that worked except the tabs didn't hover correctly. I've updated the JSfiddle with new code that works great, BUT now I have blank space to the far right of the page. Give it a look?   jsfiddle.net/jonathanmpower/ub1m3ch6/1/

Comment: Just updated the hovers :D

Comment: Works great in the JSfiddle but after uploading it to the live site it magnifies everything on a desktop monitor. Tablet and Smartphone viewing is ok. The JSfiddle i updated works perfect except for the fact that it has blank space on the right of the page. Could you help me with that one? I appreciate all of your help by the way. Thanks!!

Comment: I am do not see a blank space on the right of the page, aslo, it is magnified because i set the font-size to scale.  I changed to media queries.  As for the blank space, check for browser styles.

Comment: resize your browser window to a half screen. That's where the blank space to the right appears

Answer (score 1):

You are missing value for css in line 80:

```
  text-transform: ;
```

Plus html entities like $nbsp have ; at the end `$nbsp;`

Answer (score 1):

Set body tag to:

```
body{
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
width:1200px;
}
```

Next give #header-wrapper & #header WIDTH of  100%

```
 #header-wrapper,#header{
 width:100%;
 }
```

This should keep your #header inside of your Wrapper, and Wrapper should remain inside of your Body.

/== TAB TEXT ==/

Try replacing your #header nav a with this

```
 #header nav a {
 float:left; <!-- Changed from display:inline-block; -->
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px; <!-- changed from  0px 25px 0px 25px-->
 outline: 0;
 }
```

Comment: I've applied what you've suggested and the nav bar now renders correctly but the tab text is still justified to the left. Suggestions?

Comment: I have edited my answer to address the tab text issue